# How to validate Input type file when update image using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

When I am uploading Image then validation working properly But When I am

updating Image I  want to validate Input type file is empty or not. How  to check

it?

Actually I want to use same validation function which is using for Upload image(create image) during Update?

How can I do that?validation function is like:->

```
var teacherValidation = function() {
    // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: 
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

    var form1 = $('#form_teacher');
    var error1 = $('.alert-danger', form1);
    var success1 = $('.alert-success', form1);

    form1.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",  // validate all fields including form hidden input
        messages: {
            select_multi: {
                maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Max {0} items allowed for selection"),
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} items must be selected")
            }
        },
        rules: {

            fileData: {
                required: true

            }

        },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
            success1.show();
            error1.hide();
            form.submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try to remove required rule using  $("[name=fileData]").("remove","required") in your update page

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use your own custom function to validate the file is required in first upload and update time

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("filetype", function(value, element) {
       var types = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
       ext = value.replace(/.*[.]/, '').toLowerCase();
       if (types.indexOf(ext) !== -1) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    },"Please select allowed file");

    $('#frm').validate({
       rules:
       {
          file:
          {
              filetype: true
          }
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am talking about only update image suppose I want to update image firstly I have to fetch data from database and show on the edit form now let's assume I am not change any image I just click on the update button then error is coming field is required how to manage it

Comment: @ShahzadDitro In your case you should write your own custom function to do that which checks the file having value or not, i update my answr pls check